# Reload a page after the initial load with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a route called "./checkout" that renders embedded elements from Xola. The issue is I am using client side routing and the page needs a refresh to load the checkout page correctly (if not, Xola elements do not show up on the DOM [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJueB.png)). When I try to reload the page on the initial load I get an infinite reload loop. I can't use a href for specific reasons so I need to continue to use Next.js routing. Anyway I can go about this? EDIT: I have reached out to Xola support team for further assistance.  [image: 1]

After refresh
[image: after page is refreshed]

## checkout.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Container, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { CheckoutCard } from "../components/layout/directory";
import useIsSsr from "@/config/useSsr";

function Checkout() {
  const isSsr = useIsSsr();
  const router = useRouter();
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      {isSsr ? null : window.location.reload()}
      <Head>
        <title>checkout</title>
      </Head>
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        <Button
          className={classes.btn}
          onClick={router.back}
          color="secondary"
          variant={"contained"}
        >
          back
        </Button>
        <CheckoutCard />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: { marginTop: theme.spacing(10) },
  btn: { marginBottom: theme.spacing(5) },
}));

export default Checkout;
```

## CheckoutCard.js

```
function CheckoutCard() {
  return (
    <div
      className="xola-embedded-checkout"
      data-seller="5f3d889683cfdc77b119e592"
      data-experience="5f3d8d80d6ba9c6b14748160"
      data-version="2"
      id="xola-checkout"
    ></div>
  );
}

export default CheckoutCard;
```

Comment: Are you injecting a Xola script anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it’s being injected in the app.js and I’ve also added the script to the Head in the checkout.js and still getting the same side effects..

Answer (score 0):

Please add one more prop to CheckoutCard component calling in checkout.js. 
You need to update

```
<CheckoutCard
          url={`https://checkout.xola.com/index.html#seller/5f3d889683cfdc77b119e592/experiences/${
            url && url.slice(1)
          }?openExternal=true`}
        />
```

to

```
<CheckoutCard
          url={`https://checkout.xola.com/index.html#seller/5f3d889683cfdc77b119e592/experiences/${
            url && url.slice(1)
          }?openExternal=true`}
          key={new Date().getTime()}
        />
```

"key" prop is to identify the component and you are going to use external service ( like iframe, not sure correctly )
So in order to render the embedded elements from Xola, you should add "key" prop for CheckoutCard component calling.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have added the key and I am still receiving the same side effects...

Comment: Ok, then please add that key implementation to CheckoutCard component definition instead of calling.

Comment: Thanks, I have attempted both key implementations and still getting the same side effects.

Comment: Can you try console.log(url) in checkout.js ?
1 - try normal visiting way to go Checkout page and send that console.log message
2 - Refresh Checkout page and show me console.log message

I think the problem is related for url.
const url = isSsr ? null : window.location.search;

Comment: As of right now, the url prop isn't being used.. So that logic isn't be applied anywhere in the page or component yet. Eventually, it will pass down a url to change the checkout based on what the user selected but right now it's static and hard coded into the <div> as an attribute of "data-experience"..

Comment: I updated the code in the question to reflect what was said above 